# Жизненный цикл переменный Angular

Tags: angular

Есть код

```js
export class ArticlesComponent {

  public forecasts: ArticlesSummaryModel;
  public art: string;
  public art1: string;
  public link: number=0;

  constructor(http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.art = 'https://localhost:44356/articlechoice/' + this.route.snapshot.params['article'];
    http.get<ArticlesSummaryModel>(this.art).subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  
 }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.art1 = "assets/articles/img/" + this.forecasts.imagesContextG[0].pathimage;
  }


  onCloseButton() {
    this.link++;
    if (this.link < this.forecasts.imagesContextG.length) {
    } else {
      this.link = 0;
    }
    this.art1 = "assets/articles/img/" + this.forecasts.imagesContextG[this.link].pathimage;
  }


}

interface ArticlesSummaryModel {
  articleContextG: ArticleContextG;
  imagesContextG: ImagesContextG[];
}

interface ArticleContextG {
  ids: number;
  name: string;
  content: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  data: string;
  head: string;
}
interface ImagesContextG {
  ids: number;
  name: string;
  pathimage: string;
}
```

Интересует переменная art1, когда я нажимаю на кнопку она нормально инициализируется(получает элемент из массива forecasts.imagesContextG[this.link].pathimage и все хорошо, но вот до нажатия кнопки что-то у меня не получается ее инициализировать. Я пробовал в конструкторе, после получения данных с сервера, а также в ngOnInit и тоже не получилось, хотя вроде как после конструктора срабатывает директива ngOnInit. И я не погу понять, в каком месте инициализировать переменную по умолчанию

Comment: у тебя асинхронный код, поведение - expected.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что constructor еще до конца не получил данные, а ngOnInit уже выполнился? Странно, я думал все же инициализация происходит последовательно, а как сделать чтобы такого не было?

Comment: `http.get<ArticlesSummaryModel>(this.art).subscribe(result => this.forecasts = result)` - колбек внутри subscribe вызывается асинхронно, а не в момент вызова конструктора и перед ngOnInit.

Answer (score 0):

Все таки помогите, я честно пытаюсь разрулить вопрос, но пока не осилил. Вы меня направили в правильную сторону, я заставил работать код, но ерунда какая-то выходит. Вот получается, что теперь каждый параметр надо инициировать в конструкторе, но это выглядит мягко говоря не очень.
И далее, Вот например, если я присвоил переменной тест значение this.forecasts.articleContextG.content.

И когда пытаюсь вывести 
p>{{test}}

-Эта выполняется нормально
p>{{forecasts.articleContextG.content}} - а это выполняется, но в консоль выдает:

```
ArticlesComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'articleContextG' of undefined
```

Как сначала выполнить получение кода по запросу, а потом уже заниматься постройкой страницы?

```js
  constructor(http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.art = 'https://localhost:44356/articlechoice/' + this.route.snapshot.params['article'];
    http.get<ArticlesSummaryModel>(this.art).subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
      this.art1 = "assets/articles/img/" + this.forecasts.imagesContextG[0].pathimage;
      this.art2 = this.forecasts.imagesContextG;
      this.test = this.forecasts.articleContextG.content
    }, error => console.error(error));
    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Если тебе нужно сделать запрос, для получения данных, чтобы потом их отобразить на странице используй [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)
2. Чтобы не было ошибки, что обращаешься к undefined

> {{forecasts.articleContextG.content}}

замени на

> {{forecasts?.articleContextG?.content}}